# Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups and $Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Under my understanding of this theorem, $Z_4 \cong Z_2*Z_2$, but this is obviously false. However, 2 is prime, so why does this not fall under this theorem?

Comment: Uh, the primes have to be distinct?

Comment: Not per the theorem, the primes do not need to be distinct

Comment: What theorem are you referring to?

Comment: [This one](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups)

Comment: This says that a finitely generated Abelian group is a direct sum of **one or more** cyclic groups. In this case, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is itself a cyclic group.

Comment: You should give the link to the theorem in the QUESTION BODY. Not all readers will bother reading the comments, and the question should be self-contained anyway (meaning that ideally you should quote the theorem).

Comment: Oh, I was sort of referring to the CRT, and how $Z_{pq}\cong Z_p\times Z_q$ iff $(p, q)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Every finite abelian group is an
internal group direct product of
cyclic groups whose orders are
prime powers.
```

4 is a prime power ($2^2$), so the theorem says that an abelian group with 4 elements is either $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: @Alan you're right, let me edit